# ActiveMQ extending SimpleAuthenticationPlugin thoews NullPointerException

Tags: java, security, activemq-classic, broker

I'm not allowed to post this question unless I wrote more description instead of source code. That is why I'm just writting few more text.

I have following class. My goal is to secure the BrokerService by setting this plugin.

```
   public class MyAuthenticationPlugin extends SimpleAuthenticationPlugin {
        private String  username ="username";
        private String  password ="password";

        public MyAuthenticationPlugin(){
            secureME();
        }
        public void secureME(){
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(username, password);
            this.setUserPasswords(map);
        }
    }
```

Later I tried to use the above class as follows where I get a NullPointerException exception:-

```
    public class Server{
        private static int ackMode;
        private static String messageQueueName;
        private static String messageBrokerUrl;

        private Session session;
        private boolean transacted = false;
        private MessageProducer replyProducer;
        private MessageProtocol messageProtocol;
        private String  username ="username";
        private String  password ="password";

        static {
            messageBrokerUrl = "tcp://localhost:61616";
            messageQueueName = "client.messages";
            ackMode = Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE;
        }

        public Server() {
            try {
                //This message broker is embedded
                BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
                broker.setPersistent(false);
                broker.setUseJmx(false);
                broker.addConnector(messageBrokerUrl);
                // here I'm add my class as plguing 
                MyAuthenticationPlugin[] myAuthenticationPlugin = new 
                MyAuthenticationPlugin[1];
                myAuthenticationPlugin[0] = new MyAuthenticationPlugin();

                broker.setPlugins(myAuthenticationPlugin);
                broker.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
                //Handle the exception appropriately
            }
        }

        private void setupMessageQueueConsumer() {
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new 
               ActiveMQConnectionFactory(messageBrokerUrl);

            connectionFactory.setUserName(username);
            connectionFactory.setPassword(password);

            Connection connection;
            try {
                connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(username, password);


                connection.start(); // This line thows exception
                this.session = connection.createSession(this.transacted, ackMode);
                Destination adminQueue = this.session.createQueue(messageQueueName);

                //Setup a message producer to respond to messages from clients, we will get the destination
                //to send to from the JMSReplyTo header field from a Message
                this.replyProducer = this.session.createProducer(null);
                this.replyProducer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

                //Set up a consumer to consume messages off of the admin queue
                MessageConsumer consumer = this.session.createConsumer(adminQueue);
                consumer.setMessageListener(this);

              //  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Server();
            System.out.println("I'm done. END");
        }
    }
```

Mainly my goal is to secure my BrokerService secure by setting the username, password, access group right, etc. Please suggest me how can set username, password, access group right in BrokerService to make more secure.

**Update with stack trace:-**

```
    result = {StackTraceElement[7]@1015} 
     0 = {StackTraceElement@1016} "org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:49)"
      declaringClass = "org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport"
      methodName = "create"
      fileName = "JMSExceptionSupport.java"
      lineNumber = 49
     1 = {StackTraceElement@1017} "org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1377)"
      declaringClass = "org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection"
      methodName = "syncSendPacket"
      fileName = "ActiveMQConnection.java"
      lineNumber = 1377
     2 = {StackTraceElement@1018} "org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1481)"
      declaringClass = "org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection"
      methodName = "ensureConnectionInfoSent"
      fileName = "ActiveMQConnection.java"
      lineNumber = 1481
     3 = {StackTraceElement@1019} "org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.start(ActiveMQConnection.java:516)"
      declaringClass = "org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection"
      methodName = "start"
      fileName = "ActiveMQConnection.java"
      lineNumber = 516
     4 = {StackTraceElement@1020} "com.ma.home.Server.setupMessageQueueConsumer(Server.java:57)"
      declaringClass = "com.ma.home.Server"
      methodName = "setupMessageQueueConsumer"
      fileName = "Server.java"
      lineNumber = 57
     5 = {StackTraceElement@1021} "com.ma.home.Server.<init>(Server.java:46)"
      declaringClass = "com.ma.home.Server"
      methodName = "<init>"
      fileName = "Server.java"
      lineNumber = 46
     6 = {StackTraceElement@1022} "com.ma.home.Server.main(Server.java:84)"
      declaringClass = "com.ma.home.Server"
      methodName = "main"
      fileName = "Server.java"
      lineNumber = 84
```

Comment: Do you have the stack trace?

Comment: Please check the stack trace in the updated question. Also to reproduce the exception, you can execute the given code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to add AuthenticationUser with all three correct parameters as username, password, groups. I didn't provide groups in my code before. So follow code will fix. Also, it is working correctly.

```
        public class MyAuthenticationPlugin extends SimpleAuthenticationPlugin {
            private String  username ="username";
            private String  password ="password";
            private String  groups = "groups";

            Map<String, String> userPasswords = new HashMap<String, String>();
            List<AuthenticationUser> authenticationUserList = new ArrayList();

            public MyAuthenticationPlugin(){
                secureME();
            }
            public void secureME(){
                userPasswords.put(username, password);
                authenticationUserList.add(new AuthenticationUser(username,password, groups));
                this.setUserPasswords(userPasswords);
                this.setUsers(authenticationUserList);
            }
   }
```